# my app keep getting error back while i am trying to import an image .What to do?

Tags: python, image, error-handling, kivy

```
type here
```

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class oliveapp(App):
    def build(self):
       
        self.image=Image(source='23.jpg')
        self.button = Button(text ="button1", size_hint=(1,.1))
        
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        layout.add_widget(self.button)
        

        return layout


    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    oliveapp().run()
```

i keep getting this error  pls hlp
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <23.jpg>

I just started working with kivy and i am having an error that i have tried to fix but it didn t workout if you guys have any idea please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The program is telling you that the image cannot be found. The solution is to place the image in the working directory, that is, the folder where you are running your program. (if you're on Linux, type `echo $PWD` in the terminal to find what directory you are in) Check your Downloads folder, as it could also be in there.